# Disabling tip in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: javascript, aptana

I'm using Aptana 3. I'm selecting some fragment of code (`innerHTML`) and I want search for it in files using shortcut `Ctrl+H`. But then some tooltip is showing, and I have to press `2` key to get search dialog. How turn it off? I want seach dialog just after `Ctrl + H`.

[image]

Comment: Is this the Eclipse plugin or the standalone version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because a javascript ruble command 'Documentation for Word' is bound to Ctrl+H and so is the Eclipse 'Open Search Dialog'. You can try changing one of the two bindings:

For Open Search Dialog, go to Preferences > General > Keys and change the binding.

For the ruble command, you'd need to pull down a copy of the bundle and edit the command's binding. Commands > Javascript > Edit this Bundle, then open commands/documentation_for_word.rb and edit it.

Comment: Ok, I have it! How ever I want disable all bundles (at least JS bundles). Do you know how to do it?

Comment: As far as I know we don't have any settings/preferences to disable bundles. You can always open a ticket to request that: https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272-studio/tickets/new

Comment: It's no sens:) Beacause then shourtcuts lose meaning. Maybe I can manualy edit something to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of key bindings Aptana 3 users don't have control over in our preferences gui.  One other is 'Delete Line' command mapped to ctrl+shift+k.  i truly wish the Aptana folks would fix this key mapping issue.

Answer (score 1):

And if editing the command file does not help, here's what worked for me with Aptana Studio 3.0.1.201104291443:

1. Download the bundle with "Edit this bundle"
2. Chuck it out of the workspace (aka delete project)
3. Quit Aptana
4. Fix the problematic commands/...rb in some editor
5. Restart Aptana, retry the command and rejoice:-)